# chartist.min.js how to fixed pie color

Tags: chartist.js

I'm not very comfortable with java. I'm trying to make pie charts by setting the color based on the labels.

I use chartist.min.js

What do I need to change in my code to do this?
Thanks

Mon code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chartist.js Pie Chart avec des Libellés Personnalisés</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth" id="pie-chart"></div>

    <script>
        // Données avec libellés et valeurs
        var data = {
            labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3'],
            series: [20, 30, 50]
        };

        // Configuration du graphique
        var options = {
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        };

        // Création du graphique en secteurs
        new Chartist.Pie('#pie-chart', data, options);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript? Java and JavaScript are different. :)

Comment: Yes it's java script